# Add new parameters to custom log levels in log4j2

Tags: log4j2

Is there a way to add new parameters to custom log levels in log4j2 ?

As I saw, we can only change the log level name, but the parameters remains the same.

https://logging.apache.org/log4j/2.x/manual/customloglevels.html

Comment: Can you give an example which parameter you want do add and why?

Comment: @Uli I want to send a long and a String. Example: logger.myLogLevel(123, "Messsage"); Something like this.

Comment: The log level defines something like a severity of the logging message. I think what you want to do is to log different parameters and this has nothign to do with a log level. Please read http://musigma.org/logging/2017/11/06/logging.html as a short tutorial for logging.